# Segmentation fault in file accessing

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault

May I just ask why this piece of code is resulting to a segmentation fault. I'm trying to get input from a text file and I can't figure out what is the problem.

```
using namespace std; 
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    char str[50];
    FILE *trainfile;
    int k, n, maxval1, maxval2, classnum;
    char dataArray[n][3];

    trainfile = fopen("training.txt", "r+");

    if(trainfile == NULL){
        perror("Cannot open file.\n");
    }else{
        while(!feof(trainfile)){
            fscanf(trainfile, "%s", str);       
        }
    }
    fclose(trainfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure 50 characters is enough? also, if trainfile == NULL, you then call fclose(NULL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that your buffer might not be big enough.

You should get the size of the file first, then make a dynamic buffer of that size, and then finally read the file.

```
fseek(trainfile,0,SEEK_END); //Go to end
int size = ftell(trainfile); //Tell offset of end from beginning
char* buffer = malloc(size); //Make a buffer of the right size

fseek(ftrainfile,0,SEEK_SET); //Rewind the file

//Read file here with buffer
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int k, n, maxval1, maxval2, classnum;
char dataArray[n][3];
```

`n` is not initialized, so it can be any value and hence your code has an **Undefined Behavior**.

err...its not used anyways.

The other problem in code is your data buffer:

```
char str[50];
```

should be big enough to hold the contents of the file, which it probably is not and causes an **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: `str` doesn't need to hold the entire file, in general, just the longest sequence of contiguous non-whitespace characters. If the file is English plain text, 50 is probably enough. But there was a segfault, so the file probably wasn't.